# Column name set in stored procedure but not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

Column name set in stored procedure but not working. But when I run this script empty rows appears. What I do this for run this script?

```
Create Procedure Test
()
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @columnName nvarchar(50);

   set @columnName ='StoreName';

   SELECT * 
   FROM testtable 
   WHERE @columnName = 'storemanager'
END
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do here. You will never get results back from this procedure because your condition `@columnName = 'storemanager'` is never gonna result true. that variable is assigned with value 'storeName'

Comment: storeName is my fieldcolumn name and I want assign dynamically columns

Comment: i want this SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE StoreName = 'storemanager'

Comment: and column name is dynamically

Comment: if column name is dynamic then see my answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to use dynamic SQL because you can't reference a column with a variable - T-SQL just doesn't parse things in that order. Try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
  @columnName NVARCHAR(50),
  @value NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.testtable WHERE '
    + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' = @value;';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@value NVARCHAR(4000)', @value;
END
GO
```

`QUOTENAME()` wraps the column in `[square brackets]` and hopefully protects you from SQL injection. You should also read these posts:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [My stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist)

Comment: answer is same as mine :D but +1 for the hyperlinks :) interesting reads.

Comment: yea thats another way of looking at it hahaha

Comment: I know your not suppose to prompt user to other questions on SO but Aaron please could you please have a look at this and suggest something it will be a great great help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274485/ssrs-reports-manager-security-configuration

Comment: @MuhammedAli yes, [you absolutely should not do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88827/calling-the-attention-of-a-some-paticular-user-s-to-a-question). Besides, you need to know your audience better. I can barely spell SSRS. How many SSRS answers do you see in my profile? (And if you look closely, you'll see that most aren't even SSRS-related answers.)

Comment: ...even though they may be tagged as SSRS questions.

Comment: :( I thought since it has more to do with SQL Server Administration Stuff you would know about it. And apologies for the prompt, thanks anyway